# Lyapunov Stability for nonlinear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

I am trying to understand   attracting, Liapunov stable, asymptotically stable for given coupled system. I dont have any Liapunov function. Just two coupled systems such as

$\dot{x} = y$, $\dot{y} = -4x$

or sometimes normal systems

$\dot{x} = -x$, $\dot{y} = -5y$

How can I approach to this problem. Do I have to find the eigenvalues and then eigenvectors, write the solution etc or can it be determined just by looking at the eigenvalues ?

Or is it useful to use this diagram ?
[image]
I guess it can be determined from 
$\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{1}{2} (\tau \pm \sqrt{\tau^2 - 4\Delta})$
$\tau = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2$ and $\Delta = \lambda_1 \lambda_2$

This is a new subject to me as a physics student so I am kind of confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little of geometric qualitative insight also is worth.

For the first problem we have

$$
\cases{x\dot x = 4x y\\
4 y\dot y = - 4x y}
$$

after addition

$$
\frac 12\frac{d}{dt}(x^2+4y^2) = 0
$$

or

$$
x^2+4y^2 = C
$$

so this characterizes a center. A conservative movement which turns forever around the origin describing an ellipse.

For the second we have analogously

$$
\frac 12\frac{d}{dt}(x^2+y^2) = -(x^2+5y^2)
$$

and as $x^2+5y^2 > 0$ for $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$

we have that the movement is dissipative and goes to the origin describing stable orbits.